# In Java, can I combine these "replace" commands together?

Tags: java, replaceall

I want to remove all "{", "}",and "\"" in one string.
Now, I have to use three lines to achieve this goal, like this:

```
String a1= a.replaceAll("\\{", "");
String a2= a1.replaceAll("\"", "");
String a3= a2.replaceAll("\\}", "");
```

Can I achieve this goal using just one "replaceAll" command?

Comment: How do you combine things in regular expressions?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis. I am wondering if I can use just one "replaceAll" to make this~

Comment: And `replaceAll` takes a regular expression as its first argument. So how do you combine all characters to match into one regular expression?

Comment: @Delibz Yes you can. You also seems to know that `replaceAll` is using regex (since you escaped `{` `}` which are regex metacharacters) so you should be asking "*how can one regular expression represent `{` or `}` or `"`?*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

`String.replaceAll("[{}\\\"]", "")`

Comment: I just tried "String.replaceAll("[{}\\\"]", "")" and it works!!! Thank you and could you please explain it?

Comment: @Delibz This simply unifies the different conditions into a single Regex. `[{}\"]` will accept a match whenever it finds either of the components between []. Of course, you still have to escape the `"\"` in java